# Subgenerators for asp.net core with yeoman?

Tags: yeoman

I have just installed Yeoman, and [generator-aspnet](https://github.com/OmniSharp/generator-aspnet)

Project is created, I go to the controllers folder to add a new controller, and I get an error .
I run

```
yo aspnet:MvcController Test


You don't seem to have a generator with the name “aspnet:MvcController” installed.
```

I do npm install aspnet:MvcController but it cant find it. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hey, did you find a solution for this?

Comment: @Piero Nope. They have removed support for generators.